# Is there a way to move divs through an array?

Tags: javascript, html

*self teaching javascript* I wanted to create a menu sort of like Netflix where as you scroll right or left you can go through shows/movies, however, it would be with left and right arrows,
i.e if I moved right, block2 would be in block1 position, block3 in block2, etc

I was thinking that I could assign each block a position in an array:
var menuBar = [block1, block2, block3, block4]; then iterate through the array

```
for(var i=0; i < menuBar.length(); i++){
switch (e.key) {
            case 'ArrowLeft':
                i--;
                GoThroughMenu();
                break;
            case 'ArrowRight':
                i++;
                GoThroughMenu();
                break;
}
```

and GoThroughMenu() would move the blocks

```
block1.style.left = menuBar[i].style.left + 'px';
block1.style.top = menuBar[i].style.top + 'px';
```

Right now nothings moving, is there errors in the way I'm going about this?

Comment: Please provide a [example] using 
[StackSnippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) - because your loop doesn't really do anything as written other than produce a syntax error.

Comment: @RandyCasburn https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=CQGhMAETJ0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`left` and `top` css properties only work with a non-`position: static` value (which is the default `position` value of all elements).

Try giving the menuBar items a `position: relative;`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `position: relative;` into #box. it will work fine.

Check here working example https://jsfiddle.net/milytulip/x52goy3s/2/

```
#box{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
}
```